# Git branch -f versus soft reset

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

Does the GIT command:

```
git branch -f master master^
```

have the same effect as:

```
git reset --soft master^
```

Is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically yes, practically no. The first option does not work if `master` is your current branch. You cannot force-update the current branch with the `branch` command.

Should you be on another branch, then they are not identical either:

- the first option moves back the master branch and leaves your current branch alone
- the second option moves your current branch to the one before master, and leaves master alone.